# Django form submitted with ajax redirects to form action instead of calling success

Tags: ajax, django, forms, django-forms

I have simple form

```
class TimeForm(forms.Form):

    time = forms.TimeField()
    date = forms.DateField()

    def clean_date(self):
        time = self.cleaned_data['time']
        date = self.cleaned_data['date']
        date_time = datetime.combine(date, time)
        if datetime.now() > date_time:
            raise ValidationError("datetime error")
        return start_date
```

with class based view

```
class TimeView(View):
    @staticmethod        
    def post(request):
         form = TimeForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
             # do something
             json_data = json.dumps({'some_record': value})
         else:
             json_data = json.dumps({'errors': form.errors})
         return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json')
```

In html I have standard form with submit connected do ajax

```
<form action="/time_url/" method="POST" id="time_form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
$('#time_form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/time_url/',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            alert('yay');
        }
    })
});
</script>
```

and I'd like to be able to submit this form without page reload. Everything seems to work perfectly but success function of ajax is not triggered, instead page is redirected to /time_url/ with json data. It doesn't matter wheter form is valid nor not, it's always redirected.

I've tried also with

```
return JsonResponse(form.errors.get_json_data())
```

instead of

```
return HttpResponse(json_data, ...)
```

as suggested here [Django form submit with ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42626969/django-form-submit-with-ajax) but without success.

I'm new to javascript but for me it looks like problem with ajax, since proper data is served by server.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: If that's happening, then your JS is not being called at all; your form is being submitted normally. You need to try and work out why.

Comment: (Also, your view `post` method should *not* be a staticmethod; it should be a normal method that takes `self` as well as `request`.)

Comment: Well, you're right, JS hasn't been called, thanks.

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: Yes, but it seems that I don't have enough reputation or something to close this